# Jquery adding href to link which includes javascript function

Tags: jquery

Was looking at ways to clean up the following link :

```
    <a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());"><img src="/images/Social%20Media/pinterest.png"/></a>
```

To something like

```
<a id="pinterest><img src="/images/Social%20Media/pinterest.png"/></a>
```

and the href part through Jquery

Comment: Do you have to do it through javascript? This would obviously be better accomplished by not setting the href to a javascript function in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this

**HTML**

```
<a id="pinterest" href="">
    <img src="/images/Social%20Media/pinterest.png"/>
</a>​
```

**JS**

```
$('#pinterest').attr("href","javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());");​
```

[An example here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/uJtvV/1/). Click the image in the example to check.

Comment: Yup thats perfect. Is there way to shorten it i.e. in javascript:methodname and have all the rest in a method ?

Answer (score 0):

First think you have to do is to remove the attribute href from you link it seems like right now the only way to get it is by an element name which may not be the best idea

```
$("a").removeAttr("href")
```

and then you can add the atribute id to your link

```
$("a").attr( "id" , "pinterest");
```

Comment: I know thats fine, I guess what im asking is a cleaner way to add the href. I.e through jquery rather than in markup

Comment: well you can get href out and use eval function not sure if it helps

Answer (score 0):

If just changing the link with JS :

```
$('a[href^="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e="]').replaceWith('<a id="pinterest"><img src="/images/Social%20Media/pinterest.png"/></a>')​;
```

If you already have an external script, and can change the markup, just change the HTML to

```
<a id="pinterest"><img src="/images/Social%20Media/pinterest.png"/></a>
```

and:

```
$('#pinterest').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getScript('http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);
});
```

Heres a [FIDDLE to ->](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/uJtvV/4/) show it working ?

Comment: Getting error with $j("a#Pinterest").on is not a function

Line 74

Comment: Then your not using jQuery 1.7 or above. Just use a regular click function instead.

Comment: @StevieB - Updated my answer with a fiddle to show it actually working. If doing it this way, I'd consider changing the `<a>` element to a `<div>` or `<span>`, as you don't really need a href attribute anymore, and an `<a>` element should have a href attribute.